# android location getting null need solution

Tags: android, gps, location

```
String logloc ="";
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
if (location!=null) {
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    logloc = String.valueOf(latitude)+","+String.valueOf(longitude);
    notfi(logloc); 
}
```

in this above code my location is always getting null even my gps device is on and both outside the building and inside the building , i'm getting null value only , kindly help me run this code

Comment: Dis you add the permissions in manifest file?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />  this permission has been added after </application> tag

Comment: [refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16393534/2345913). There it check if GPS or NETWORKPROVIDER is enabled or not first before processing.

Comment: Please add ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just becuase your device has not the last known location, thats why. First make the code for `onLocationChanged()`. It will get the current location and save it as `lastKnownLocation`. Then the method will work.

You can take help for current location here

[How do I get the current GPS location programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: thanks for your reply , what about lm ?  we getting getLastKnownLocation  using lm.getLastKnownLocation

Comment: your code is fine, but that time no current location you need to used locationlistner and automatically triger OnLocationChanged and get the current lat and long

Answer (score 0):

try like this your Activity must be like this

`Activity extends MapActivity implements LocationListener`

```
 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
 Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
 String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
 Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        lat = (double) (location.getLatitude());
        lng = (double) (location.getLongitude());

        Log.i(TAG, "Lattitude:" + lat);
        Log.i(TAG, "Longitude:" + lng);

    }
```